# Error message for virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am facing issues when I start new session on terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

So I followed the instructions on the [Error message for virtualenvwrapper on OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199360/error-message-for-virtualenvwrapper-on-os-x-lion).

Now the error is:

```
-bash: /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

Not sure how to solve this..

Need some guidance..

Edit:

```
 Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8    
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: Are you using Python installed by brew, or the python.org installer? Chances are you have multiple Python installations and the wrapper script is installed on an alternate (non-default) Python.

Comment: how to remove the multiple python installations?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these lines to your shell startup file (`.bashrc`, `.profile`..):

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After that type `source .bashrc` or `source .profile` depending on your startup file, and you should be fine.

Comment: the old error comes out.. Will paste what is inside bash_profile in the question..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using or installing virtualenv for Python3, Ensure u have the `Python3` file in `/usr/local/bin` directory. Then you can use the line below in your .bashrc or .zshrc(for zsh) file under the virtualenv wrapper configurations.

`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3`

Otherwise if you are installing for python 2.7 normally the Python file is in the `/usr/bin/` directory so you can update your `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` in the .bashrc or .zshrc(for zsh) to be:

`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`

NB: Remember to use `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`  when installing for python3

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the paths are correct. On my machine that script is located here:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```